# MySQL client 8.0 showing "fwrite: Broken pipe" on large query when using a pager

Tags: linux, mysql, mysql8, less

I have always been using a pager (`--pager="less -SFX"` to be more specific) for MySQL client. Previously I was on version 5.6 of MySQL client/server and it was doing great.  Recently I started to use MySQL client/server version 8.0, and the client started showing `fwrite: Broken pipe` on large query result:

```
+------+-------------------------------------------+-----------------+-----------+-------+--------+-------------+-----------------+----------------------------+----------------------------+-------------+---------------------+----------------------------+----------------
| id   | file                                      | content_type    | file_size | width | height | orientation | cln_customer_id | created_at                 | updated_at                 | uploader_id | uploader_type       | taken_at                   | customer_visibl
+------+-------------------------------------------+-----------------+-----------+-------+--------+-------------+-----------------+----------------------------+----------------------------+-------------+---------------------+----------------------------+----------------
|    1 | 9f3c8b92-9501-475e-8848-a115141a546f.png  | image/png       |     41665 |  1300 |    551 |        NULL |              15 | 2019-11-18 02:50:10.000000 | 2019-11-18 02:50:10.000000 |       16054 | Clover::User        | 2019-11-18 02:50:10.000000 |
|    2 | 655c35f2-d7a7-41a9-8814-a56d7398a5fd.png  | image/png       |     36674 |  1300 |    551 |        NULL |              15 | 2019-11-18 02:50:20.000000 | 2019-11-18 02:50:20.000000 |       16054 | Clover::User        | 2019-11-18 02:50:20.000000 |
|    3 | a1209273-3df6-4a7f-a94e-adcebe005e46.jpg  | image/jpeg      |     76467 |   600 |    600 |           1 |              16 | 2019-11-18 07:03:56.000000 | 2019-11-18 07:03:56.000000 |       16054 | Clover::User        | 2019-11-18 07:03:56.000000 |
|    4 | 09ef833b-128c-42bb-b2f8-63a3c91e5266.jpg  | image/jpeg      |     76467 |   600 |    600 |           1 |              16 | 2019-11-18 07:04:13.000000 | 2019-11-18 07:04:13.000000 |       16054 | Clover::User        | 2019-11-18 07:04:13.000000 |
|    5 | 52744941-2e06-450b-b4d4-3e996158bc5b.jpg  | image/jpeg      |    122074 |  1440 |    866 |        NULL |              16 | 2019-11-19 08:17:21.000000 | 2019-11-19 08:17:21.000000 |        NULL | NULL                | 2019-11-19 08:17:21.000000 |
|    6 | 45d952c0-2d28-4a55-a620-02cbb1a21108.jpg  | image/jpeg      |    122074 |  1440 |    866 |        NULL |              16 | 2019-11-19 08:17:37.000000 | 2019-11-19 08:17:37.000000 |        NULL | NULL                | 2019-11-19 08:17:37.000000 |
|    7 | ee3ae126-a639-4c67-97de-36355cd2abd1.jpg  | image/jpeg      |     95989 |  1200 |   1600 |           1 |              16 | 2019-11-19 08:18:00.000000 | 2020-08-15 10:21:30.000000 |        NULL | NULL                | 2018-01-11 00:27:13.000000 |
|    8 | b2c1e2f0-28aa-4c97-9041-76227cf2bc2e.jpg  | image/jpeg      |     76467 |   600 |    600 |           1 |              16 | 2019-11-19 08:18:21.000000 | 2019-11-19 08:18:21.000000 |        NULL | NULL                | 2019-11-19 08:18:21.000000 |
|   23 | f9436ac5-1d6e-4dcf-bd38-ab26078d37ec.jpg  | image/jpeg      |     76467 |   600 |    600 |           1 |              16 | 2019-11-19 08:39:06.000000 | 2019-11-19 08:39:06.000000 |        NULL | NULL                | 2019-11-19 08:39:06.000000 |
|   24 | de272f71-c397-4059-b7f8-da62038de195.jpg  | image/jpeg      |     63100 |   960 |   1280 |        NULL |              28 | 2019-11-19 08:59:06.000000 | 2019-11-21 10:11:08.000000 |        NULL | NULL                | 2019-11-19 08:59:06.000000 |
|   25 | 043c98b5-fe90-46fa-948c-e40ef53e1d8c.jpg  | image/jpeg      |     51291 |   960 |   1280 |        NULL |              28 | 2019-11-19 08:59:16.000000 | 2019-11-19 08:59:16.000000 |        NULL | NULL                | 2019-11-19 08:59:16.000000 |
|   26 | 10481989-e723-420f-9cfc-ffb16a467b55.jpg  | image/jpeg      |     49650 |  1280 |    960 |        NULL |              28 | 2019-11-19 08:59:27.000000 | 2019-11-19 08:59:27.000000 |        NULL | NULL                | 2019-11-19 08:59:27.000000 |
|   27 | 1449a37b-a1e2-4ba2-89b2-8baa48eb9908.jpg  | image/jpeg      |     63100 |   960 |   1280 |        NULL |              28 | 2019-11-19 08:59:27.000000 | 2019-11-19 08:59:27.000000 |        NULL | NULL                | 2019-11-19 08:59:27.000000 |
|   28 | d2ab04c2-debe-46b5-a85a-c52d2c96edf9.jpg  | image/jpeg      |     51291 |   960 |   1280 |        NULL |              28 | 2019-11-19 08:59:27.000000 | 2019-11-19 08:59:27.000000 |        NULL | NULL                | 2019-11-19 08:59:27.000000 |
|   29 | 655f1911-6ec5-491e-b2f6-c328051c3b31.jpg  | image/jpeg      |     63759 |   960 |   1280 |        NULL |              28 | 2019-11-19 08:59:27.000000 | 2019-11-21 10:10:51.000000 |        NULL | NULL                | 2019-11-19 08:59:27.000000 |
|   30 | 5329c902-fe4a-4b1e-b71d-d30b2fbbb34b.JPG  | image/jpeg      |   2751465 |  5184 |   3456 |           1 |              28 | 2019-11-19 08:59:45.000000 | 2020-08-15 10:21:31.000000 |        NULL | NULL                | 2019-07-03 08:45:22.000000 |
|   31 | e03c9a83-d282-4e57-b6f4-aab09b342561.JPG  | image/jpeg      |   2697520 |  5184 |   3456 |           1 |              28 | 2019-11-19 08:59:45.000000 | 2020-08-15 10:21:31.000000 |        NULL | NULL                | 2019-07-03 08:43:40.000000 |
|   58 | 1941f326-78b9-445d-adce-69631964136e.jpg  | image/jpeg      |    122074 |  1440 |    866 |        NULL |              28 | 2019-11-19 10:41:53.000000 | 2019-11-19 10:41:53.000000 |        NULL | NULL                | 2019-11-19 10:41:53.000000 |
|   59 | ae3b1113-c4e5-4481-94de-ab492aad334f.jpg  | image/jpeg      |    122074 |  1440 |    866 |        NULL |              28 | 2019-11-19 10:45:51.000000 | 2019-11-19 10:45:51.000000 |        NULL | NULL                | 2019-11-19 10:45:51.000000 |
|   60 | 10f254a6-d1b4-45f5-af0e-450a5ecfca05.png  | image/png       |     23282 |   175 |    175 |        NULL |              28 | 2019-11-19 10:45:51.000000 | 2019-11-21 10:11:03.000000 |        NULL | NULL                | 2019-11-19 10:45:51.000000 |
|   61 | dfb94c00-d28a-404b-8c11-b3dcf3653eef.jpg  | image/jpeg      |    122074 |  1440 |    866 |        NULL |              28 | 2019-11-19 10:52:06.000000 | 2019-11-21 10:10:54.000000 |        NULL | NULL                | 2019-11-19 10:52:06.000000 |
|   62 | b2e24738-c140-45ca-89c1-2349e4244379.jpg  | image/jpeg      |     95989 |  1200 |   1600 |           1 |              28 | 2019-11-19 10:52:24.000000 | 2020-08-15 10:21:32.000000 |        NULL | NULL                | 2018-01-11 00:27:13.000000 |
|   63 | 7c049beb-2a37-4bc5-af07-ae102f70e4ce.jpg  | image/jpeg      |    122074 |  1440 |    866 |        NULL |              28 | 2019-11-19 10:52:24.000000 | 2019-11-19 10:52:24.000000 |        NULL | NULL                | 2019-11-19 10:52:24.000000 |
|   64 | 4428ff0d-2714-4c96-b649-405b60fc6833.jpg  | image/jpeg      |   4186415 |  4000 |   3000 |           1 |              25 | 2019-11-20 02:11:10.000000 | 2019-11-20 02:11:10.000000 |       15054 | Clover::User        | 2019-11-20 02:11:10.000000 |
|  146 | 483cf7ac-4a96-4cc2-bf79-4ed1002bd047.png  | image/png       |     76578 |  2481 |   2481 |        NULL |              28 | 2019-11-21 15:41:43.000000 | 2019-11-26 05:48:08.000000 |       15054 | Clover::User        | 2019-11-21 15:41:43.000000 |
|  147 | e401414e-7b2d-4588-9d53-825d5d614694.png  | image/png       |     23282 |   175 |    175 |        NULL |              28 | 2019-11-22 03:30:50.000000 | 2019-11-26 05:07:40.000000 |       16054 | Clover::User        | 2019-11-22 03:30:50.000000 |
|  148 | 4d965b81-0f0b-4967-b402-27c0be360994.jpeg | image/jpeg      |     94853 |  1080 |   1440 |        NULL |              26 | 2019-11-22 09:44:12.000000 | 2019-11-22 09:50:53.000000 |       15054 | Clover::User        | 2019-11-22 09:44:12.000000 |
|  149 | 890f70a8-2dc6-4287-ba63-d2eb821ffce6.jpeg | image/jpeg      |     95042 |  1080 |   1440 |        NULL |              26 | 2019-11-22 09:44:12.000000 | 2019-11-22 09:49:19.000000 |       15054 | Clover::User        | 2019-11-22 09:44:12.000000 |
|  150 | bc107f90-3784-4080-ab5b-24a1d514a95f.jpeg | image/jpeg      |    130836 |  1080 |   1440 |        NULL |              26 | 2019-11-22 09:44:13.000000 | 2019-11-22 09:44:13.000000 |       15054 | Clover::User        | 2019-11-22 09:44:13.000000 |
|  151 | f4c71856-64a7-424d-a012-3309bc57f2a6.jpeg | image/jpeg      |    144424 |  1080 |   1440 |        NULL |              26 | 2019-11-22 09:44:13.000000 | 2019-11-22 09:50:12.000000 |       15054 | Clover::User        | 2019-11-22 09:44:13.000000 |
|  152 | 775be35d-c0db-4c6d-8b90-90a8542c3b86.jpg  | image/jpeg      |    228831 |   960 |   1280 |           1 |              29 | 2019-11-22 09:44:42.000000 | 2019-11-22 09:48:53.000000 |       16054 | Clover::User        | 2019-11-22 09:44:42.000000 |
|  153 | 576e2e9b-227e-4472-ab90-2dbc4d6567a1.JPG  | image/jpeg      |   4576317 |  5184 |   3456 |           8 |              29 | 2019-11-22 09:44:47.000000 | 2019-11-22 09:52:37.000000 |       16054 | Clover::User        | 2019-11-20 03:00:09.000000 |
|  154 | 650af5ce-23a5-4bc1-ac20-34a6aaad4d6a.JPG  | image/jpeg      |   5773855 |  5184 |   3456 |           8 |              29 | 2019-11-22 09:44:48.000000 | 2019-11-22 09:52:38.000000 |       16054 | Clover::User        | 2019-11-20 02:59:39.000000 |
|  155 | b6b3830a-0649-4d6c-88ee-b66b85a6b76f.JPG  | image/jpeg      |   4744838 |  5184 |   3456 |           8 |              29 | 2019-11-22 09:44:49.000000 | 2019-11-22 09:52:40.000000 |       16054 | Clover::User        | 2019-11-20 02:59:31.000000 |
|  156 | 9fe39409-4604-4ce0-941d-007a9010dd2f.jpg  | image/jpeg      |    122074 |  1440 |    866 |        NULL |              29 | 2019-11-22 09:44:59.000000 | 2019-11-22 10:00:10.000000 |       16054 | Clover::User        | 2019-11-22 09:44:59.000000 |
|  157 | ed17d28c-9172-4fdb-8305-edf9f8fe049f.jpeg | image/jpeg      |   1732122 |  4032 |   3024 |           6 |              29 | 2019-11-22 09:47:23.000000 | 2019-11-22 09:47:23.000000 |       16054 | Clover::User        | 2019-11-05 04:36:39.000000 |
|  158 | f982f60f-fdcb-4666-8865-420ee545da29.jpeg | image/jpeg      |    497403 |  3648 |   2736 |           0 |              29 | 2019-11-22 09:48:03.000000 | 2019-11-22 09:48:03.000000 |       16054 | Clover::User        | 2019-09-13 15:39:54.000000 |
|  159 | 3c9eeb96-47ef-4e34-b081-4f52679bc71b.jpeg | image/jpeg      |   2047502 |  4032 |   3024 |           1 |              26 | 2019-11-22 09:51:41.000000 | 2019-11-22 09:51:52.000000 |       15054 | Clover::User        | 2019-11-21 08:11:08.000000 |
|  160 | 13ca5568-7c1d-4c80-b833-b75d7a13d44d.JPG  | image/jpeg      |   4576317 |  5184 |   3456 |           8 |              55 | 2019-11-29 08:29:07.000000 | 2019-11-29 10:01:53.000000 |       16054 | Clover::User        | 2019-11-20 03:00:09.000000 |
|  161 | ec66d057-4ab2-4886-a935-074b13446e88.jpg  | image/jpeg      |    228831 |   960 |   1280 |           1 |              55 | 2019-11-29 08:29:17.000000 | 2019-12-01 09:46:57.000000 |       16054 | Clover::User        | 2019-11-29 08:29:17.000000 |
|  162 | 3d76aed4-0f58-43f8-9825-339119bf5958.JPG  | image/jpeg      |   5773855 |  5184 |   3456 |           8 |              55 | 2019-11-29 08:29:23.000000 | 2019-12-01 09:46:40.000000 |       16054 | Clover::User        | 2019-11-20 02:59:39.000000 |
|  163 | c0485c94-f792-46af-92fe-6cd36d169b2b.JPG  | image/jpeg      |   4744838 |  5184 |   3456 |           8 |              55 | 2019-11-29 08:29:33.000000 | 2019-12-01 09:47:32.000000 |       16054 | Clover::User        | 2019-11-20 02:59:31.000000 |
|  164 | 5fd036b3-53d0-40c0-9bae-c712bd8cb983.jpg  | image/jpeg      |    228831 |   960 |   1280 |           1 |              55 | 2019-12-05 03:26:27.000000 | 2019-12-05 03:29:53.000000 |       16054 | Clover::User        | 2019-12-05 03:26:27.000000 |
|  165 | 482030f8-69f4-44fc-8b7b-d18e62bdf7f1.JPG  | image/jpeg      |   4744838 |  5184 |   3456 |           8 |              55 | 2019-12-05 03:27:51.000000 | 2019-12-05 03:29:06.000000 |       16054 | Clover::User        | 2019-11-20 02:59:31.000000 |
|  166 | bf0f6e65-4922-4407-bc4f-f2a73684aceb.JPG  | image/jpeg      |   5773855 |  5184 |   3456 |           8 |              55 | 2019-12-05 03:27:51.000000 | 2019-12-05 03:27:51.000000 |       16054 | Clover::User        | 2019-11-20 02:59:39.000000 |
|  167 | 4638d444-3bd6-4a82-a1a0-4e340d24a813.JPG  | image/jpeg      |   4576317 |  5184 |   3456 |           8 |              57 | 2019-12-05 03:35:21.000000 | 2019-12-09 02:05:20.000000 |       16054 | Clover::User        | 2019-11-20 03:00:09.000000 |
|  168 | 56a78d51-254b-4c76-88a4-df13596251c1.JPG  | image/jpeg      |   5773855 |  5184 |   3456 |           8 |              57 | 2019-12-05 03:35:21.000000 | 2019-12-09 02:05:13.000000 |       16054 | Clover::User        | 2019-11-20 02:59:39.000000 |
|  169 | 84974ca6-c000-4a0d-88f8-7693019784bc.jpg  | image/jpeg      |    228831 |   960 |   1280 |           1 |              57 | 2019-12-05 03:35:21.000000 | 2019-12-05 07:36:20.000000 |       16054 | Clover::User        | 2019-12-05 03:35:21.000000 |
|  170 | 41563fe0-5945-4c83-bd6b-ad1594109457.JPG  | image/jpeg      |   4744838 |  5184 |   3456 |           8 |              57 | 2019-12-05 03:35:22.000000 | 2019-12-06 09:42:38.000000 |       16054 | Clover::User        | 2019-11-20 02:59:31.000000 |
|  171 | 6f5c7a6d-81c0-43be-ae84-af5c256363ff.png  | image/png       |     38667 |  1300 |    551 |        NULL |               3 | 2019-12-05 05:10:38.000000 | 2019-12-05 05:11:09.000000 |       16055 | Clover::User        | 2019-12-05 05:10:38.000000 |
|  172 | 2a583861-6779-4cff-b1be-1d3f20ba58d1.jpeg | image/jpeg      |     95042 |  1080 |   1440 |        NULL |              58 | 2019-12-08 04:46:30.000000 | 2019-12-08 04:47:14.000000 |       15054 | Clover::User        | 2019-12-08 04:46:30.000000 |
|  173 | 461e86df-b3c6-4c2b-9d65-494fd9892001.jpeg | image/jpeg      |     94853 |  1080 |   1440 |        NULL |              58 | 2019-12-08 04:46:30.000000 | 2019-12-08 04:47:53.000000 |       15054 | Clover::User        | 2019-12-08 04:46:30.000000 |
|  174 | 654db564-d3ae-4d96-a9d5-23bd9ac2e444.jpeg | image/jpeg      |     83010 |  1080 |   1440 |        NULL |              58 | 2019-12-08 14:16:43.000000 | 2019-12-08 14:16:43.000000 |       15054 | Clover::User        | 2019-12-08 14:16:43.000000 |
|  175 | 91e8dddc-5ef7-4fea-876e-18aa9968c789.jpeg | image/jpeg      |     77288 |  1080 |   1440 |        NULL |              58 | 2019-12-08 14:16:43.000000 | 2019-12-08 14:16:43.000000 |       15054 | Clover::User        | 2019-12-08 14:16:43.000000 |
|  176 | ec391232-8c9d-4c77-801b-351f6509a9fd.jpeg | image/jpeg      |     85038 |  1080 |   1440 |        NULL |              58 | 2019-12-08 14:16:43.000000 | 2019-12-08 14:16:43.000000 |       15054 | Clover::User        | 2019-12-08 14:16:43.000000 |
|  177 | df130d1b-aa6e-46a2-b11d-df5fae6fe289.jpeg | image/jpeg      |     89938 |  1080 |   1440 |        NULL |              58 | 2019-12-08 14:16:43.000000 | 2019-12-08 14:16:43.000000 |       15054 | Clover::User        | 2019-12-08 14:16:43.000000 |
|  178 | 977a8600-683d-40ca-b603-6a09f7c83930.jpeg | image/jpeg      |     73886 |  1080 |   1440 |        NULL |              58 | 2019-12-08 14:16:43.000000 | 2019-12-08 14:16:43.000000 |       15054 | Clover::User        | 2019-12-08 14:16:43.000000 |
|  179 | 3049c423-dc8c-4262-8ee0-87b086c754db.jpeg | image/jpeg      |     72657 |  1080 |   1440 |        NULL |              58 | 2019-12-08 14:16:43.000000 | 2019-12-08 14:16:43.000000 |       15054 | Clover::User        | 2019-12-08 14:16:43.000000 |
|  180 | 507e8b77-5e3c-4aad-b272-3be276eee2fb.jpeg | image/jpeg      |    144424 |  1080 |   1440 |        NULL |              58 | 2019-12-08 14:17:41.000000 | 2019-12-08 14:17:41.000000 |       16065 | Clover::User        | 2019-12-08 14:17:41.000000 |
|  181 | 3dac7119-704b-4389-a387-c3d5482785aa.jpeg | image/jpeg      |    130836 |  1080 |   1440 |        NULL |              58 | 2019-12-08 14:17:41.000000 | 2019-12-08 14:17:41.000000 |       16065 | Clover::User        | 2019-12-08 14:17:41.000000 |
|  182 | f750220a-8860-4f49-92df-8165501841c4.jpg  | image/jpeg      |   1768676 |  4032 |   3024 |           1 |              58 | 2019-12-08 14:21:26.000000 | 2019-12-08 14:21:26.000000 |       16065 | Clover::User        | 2019-08-07 03:14:54.000000 |
|  183 | c4a9edd6-a0a9-4403-8b55-4e90e7ee9290.jpg  | image/jpeg      |   1785633 |  4032 |   3024 |           1 |              58 | 2019-12-08 14:21:26.000000 | 2019-12-08 14:21:26.000000 |       16065 | Clover::User        | 2019-08-07 03:15:06.000000 |
fwrite: Broken pipe
fwrite: Broken pipe
fwrite: Broken pipe
2632 rows in set (0.01 sec)
mysql>
```

Some notes on the error:

- The error messages got printed on the screen as soon as I hit the `q` key.
- The number of lines of error messages becomes less when more part of the query result gets viewed (for example, by navigating down with the `pagedown` key before hitting the `q` key). If the last page of the query result is reached (either all the way through with the `pagedown` key or directly with the `end` key skipping all the pages in-between), then no error message will show up after I hit the `q` key.
- By saying "large query result", I have't found a precise measure yet. It's definitely not just "lager than one screen page". It seems it's not just about the number of rows of the query result. The error occurred on a 2632 rows result with 22 columns, but didn't occur on a 157161 rows result with 5 columns.
- The problem gets worse on even larger query result. I intentionally executed a query with several `JOIN` on large tables, and the pager seemed not doing its job at all. The query result flooded on the screen without stopping for my keyboard input and the MySQL client process eventually consumed up all running memory of the machine. This never happened before when I used the 5.6 client with a pager, no matter how large the query result was.
- The problem seems to be relevant only to the client program. I tried using the 8.0 client to connect to a 5.6 server (the one which worked well with the 5.6 client before) and the error still popped up.
- The problem remained the same when using `less` without the `-SFX` options.
- The problem is not bound to the specific pager program `less`. I tried using `more` as the pager and it was about the same.
- The exact version of the MySQL client in problem is `8.0.31`.
- I am on `Centos 7.9`.

I did quite a search for similar issues but no luck so far.

Comment: Sounds like this should be a bug report: bugs.mysql.com

Comment: @RickJames I already submitted a bug report, but the verification team said they can't reproduce the issue on Oracle Linux and took it as a conclusion. https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=109297

Comment: Does it fail without `-SFX`?  In which case, which option is causing the problem?

Comment: @RickJames I did try `less` without any options, the problem remained the same.  I should have included this in the question post.  Thank you for bringing this up.

Comment: @goodbyeera, can you clarify what you're asking to solve. Is the fact than an error message is shown the issue or is there some other, more severe issue that actually breaks some functionality? There are two issues described here, the presence of an error message with little to no consequence and the malfunctioning pager when JOINing large tables. The broken pipe seems "normal" to me insofar as you're effectively disconnecting before draining the result, the pager not working seems to be the only real issue but also the less detailed one.

Answer (score 1):

The "fwrite: Broken pipe" error occurs when you're using the MySql client with the pager process.

The issue triggers when the pager process (in your case `less`) closes the output stream before the MySQL client finish writing its output. Sometimes you find this error when you "violently" stop the pager or if your output hits a certain limit.

Now, how to fix that? There are many ways to avoid this.

First, you can try adding `-F` flag to your `less` pager to avoid any sudden interruptions if a long stream occurs. With `-F` flag you're allowing the MySql client to finish the output.

Secondly, you can use `-X` and `-S` flags to format your output and check the output even if your `less`command is stopped.

Another useful flag is the `-j` flag to start viewing your output from a specific point. This can be helpful if you know that your MySQL will *vomit* a long output.

If I was in your place I would play with different combination of flags in `less` command

e.g. `--pager="less -SFX -j<line_number>"`

to find the most suitable for my case.